# Hide/unhide UISearchBar and large title just like iMessage

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uinavigationitem

I have looked through dozens of posts/youtube videos to try to achieve this.

My searchbar is currently set like so:

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
```

it is set to be initially hidden and once I scroll down, it reveals without issues.

The problem is when I scroll up and "compact" it, it will not stay hidden under the navigation bar but instead jumps right back down again and stays visible.

**I'm trying to achieve the exact same thing as in the iMessage app**, where you can hide/unhide the search bar and large title by dragging down/pushing up the tableView.

Much appreciated :)